# I am using FastAPI and if I dont put anything on JSON obj the value in my database changes in "string"

Tags: fastapi

[image]

#==== schemas.py =======================================

from typing import(Optional)

from pydantic import BaseModel

from datetime import date

class showBlog(BaseModel):

```
ID: int
ORNo: Optional[str]
Status: Optional[str]
TradeName: Optional[str]
ApplicationDate: Optional[date]
PaymentMade1: Optional[float]

class Config():
    orm_mode = True
```

#===== models.py ================================================

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime, Numeric
from app.dbapi.database import Base

class BLOG(Base):
**tablename** = 'my_db'

```
ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
ORNo = Column(String)
Status = Column(String)
TradeName = Column(String)
ApplicationDate = Column(DateTime)
```

### PLEASE SEE ATTACHED IMAGE. IT CHANGES MY DATA VALUE INTO "string" "string" if I execute the JSON obj without putting some values. How can I set the default value coming from my database?

[inserted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sACUH.png)

Comment: What is the relevant code for how you're sending this to your database from your endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I am sending it from my end point and 

{
 
  
  "Status": "string",
  
}

if I execute it values in my database changes to "string"

Comment: I'm thinking about _the code_. I.e. your controller - the part of the code that handle whatever is being sent to your service and then storing it in the database. I'm guessing that's the _response_, not the _request_ you included in your comment.

Comment: schemas.py what handles for data storing (the code I've posted above). Is it possible to have that schemas.py default value coming from my database?

Comment: If you're sending `{"Status": "string"}` to your endpoint, you shouldn't be surprised that the value changes to `string`. But I think there's a misunderstanding here - I'm guessing you're sending actual data and not just the value `string`. You also need to have a controller somewhere, where you're taking data from the user and sending it to your database - how that looks (and thus, how you're updating the db itself by populating the model object) is important and needs to be included in your question.

Comment: I get your point. It give some clear solutions for me.

 Is it possible to get the data like this? 
 {"Status": BLOG.status } so that if I run my PUT end point the default value of status is the actual value in my database?